# Access Unmatched Query multiple like records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access

Question: Is there a way to make the unmatched query return the records that have multiple items but the same information?

I am running an unmatched query against a table and an SQL query.  Everything works for the records that do not exist in the query.  My issue lies in that records that should be repeated are not recognized when more than one record exists in the query.

These are aircraft parts that are required to be installed and tracked.  Each part has code associated with its location `LOC`. In some cases the parts have the same `LOC` code but multiple parts are installed.

Example: In one case we have 8 bolts that are installed.  The table lists each bolt individually and they all have the same `LOC`. If only one bolt is installed, the unmatched query does not return a value for the 7 remaining bolts that are not installed. It sees the one bolt and moves on.

Is there a way to make the unmatched query return the records that have multiple items but the same `LOC` and `Name`?

```
SELECT [MCDS-E].MODEL, [MCDS-E].LOC, [MCDS-E].NOMENCLATURE, [MCDS-E].CHANGE_TYPE,
       [MCDS-E].TBO, [MCDS-E].CHANGE_NUMBER, [MCDS-E].DA2410, 
       [MCDS-E].LOCAL_TRACKED, [MCDS-E].COMMENTS    
FROM [MCDS-E] 
LEFT JOIN Select_ACFT ON [MCDS-E].[LOC] = Select_ACFT.[LOC]    
WHERE ((([MCDS-E].MODEL)=Forms!Index!Text5) 
   AND ((Select_ACFT.LOC) Is Null));
```

My table might have:

```
    LOC        NOMENCLATURE

 - ABCD123     Bolt
 - ABCD123     Bolt 
 - ABCD123     Bolt 
 - ABCD123     Bolt
```

The query might have :

```
    LOC        NOMENCLATURE
 - ABCD123     Bolt
```

The match query would not show any results for the other three ABCD123 Bolts that are not installed.

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: GROUP BY loc and name and SUM or COUNT the part

Comment: I added the code from the access sql query

Comment: In your example data, what field is *Bolt* -the `Nomenclature`, `LOC` or even `Model`? I have an answer but might be confusing how pieces relate. Unmatched query should return all `LOC` unless this it the field that indicates *installed*.

Comment: Basically, we have components installed on aircraft and each component has a serial number.  I am trying to find where components are not installed (no record) in the same location.  Like I mentioned above.  like an aircraft may have 4 rotor blades and all have the same location 123ABC but only three are installed in the computer.  I am trying to match a table of all the components against a query of installed components and find those that are not installed.

Comment: When I do it, I get the unmatched components but if there are multiple parts in the same location and one of several is installed it does not show the remaining components that are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining back your query resultset to original table as current query returns unmatched records. Once those particular `LOC` are found, join back to full `[MCDS-E]` table for related items.

Below assumes *Name* is the `NOMENCLATURE` field used as the join back o main:

```
SELECT main.MODEL, main.LOC, main.NOMENCLATURE, main.CHANGE_TYPE,
       main.TBO, main.CHANGE_NUMBER, main.DA2410, 
       main.LOCAL_TRACKED, main.COMMENTS  
FROM [MCDS-E] main
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT m.[LOC], m.NOMENCLATURE
   FROM [MCDS-E] m
   LEFT JOIN Select_ACFT s ON m.[LOC] = s.[LOC]    
   WHERE ((([MCDS-E].MODEL)=Forms!Index!Text5) 
      AND ((Select_ACFT.LOC) Is Null))) AS dT
ON dT.NOMENCLATURE = main.NOMENCLATURE
```

Alternatively, saving above nested `SELECT` as its own query:

```
SELECT main.MODEL, main.LOC, main.NOMENCLATURE, main.CHANGE_TYPE,
       main.TBO, main.CHANGE_NUMBER, main.DA2410, 
       main.LOCAL_TRACKED, main.COMMENTS  
FROM [MCDS-E] main
INNER JOIN [UnmatchedQuery] u
ON main.NOMENCLATURE = u.NOMENCLATURE
```

Comment: Unfortunately the nomenclature doesn't exist in both tables.  I am trying to take the information from the query and add the nomenclature back to it and then use the information above.  Sorry, I am not the sharpest knife in the drawer so this is still taking some time.  to prove my point...I am a little confused by the m, s, u and dt above.  can you expound on what that means?

Comment: This query joins tables on `LOC` and matches `NOMENCLATURE` from `[MCD-E]`. The letters are simply table aliases (temporary "nicknames") to avoid retyping the longer, full table name like `[MDCE-E]` and it helps differentiate between both `[MCD-E]` references as it is called twice.